# getting TypeInitializationException Oracle.DataAccess

Tags: c#, oracle

I have Windows 10 machine. In that I am running a c# project which references `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`. I have installed **ODAC112012_32Bit**. There is a dll `NexFen.FirmLoad` which accesses Oracle dll. When I run the project I get following error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'NexGen.FirmLoad.AppUtils' threw an exception. --->
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) --->
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.1.2, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at NexGen.FirmLoad.AppUtils..cctor()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at NexGen.FirmLoad.LoadFirmware.d__0.MoveNext()

Comment: Check, if your program is **32-bit** (since you are trying to load **32-bit** assembly)

Comment: I have tried with  both 32 bit and 64 bit program, but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your project meets all the following conditions:

- You have an Oracle client installed (e.g. Oracle Instant Client)
- `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` and the Oracle Client and the compile target of your application have **all** the same architecture (i.e. 32-bit vs. 64-bit)
- Version of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` is the same version as your Oracle client (even the minor version has to match). Your error message indicates version `4.112.3.0` and `4.112.1.2`, perhaps there is your problem. Check installed versions in your GAC and Policies.

Comment: I have checked installed version in GAC. In GAC-32 it's 4.112.1.2 and in GAC-64 it was 4.112.3.0 which I have uninstalled as my project was referring to 4.112.1.2 version so.

Comment: @kanika, in case you like to use 32-bit and 64-bit have a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100